# How do I nestle a table inside prototype?

Tags: html, html-table

This is the current code I have:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
a { text-decoration:none }
</style>
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ParaStyle.css" />  
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie6-only2.css" />  
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only2.css" />
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.2.74.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/javascript.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    var $ = jQuery;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Wrapper">
<div id="Hidebutton"><button id="hidr"><font color="#494A4A"><b>X</b></font></button></div>
<div id="cse-search-form" style= "z-index:999997; top:0px;"></div>
<div id="cse-search-form" style="width: 100%;"></div>
<div id="cse" style="width:43%; z-index:999996; top:40px;"></div>
<script src="googlejs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<ul id="dropdown">
<li><a href="index.php"><b>Home</b></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><b>Products</b></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="gas_boosters.php">Gas Boosters</a></li>
        <li><a href="valve_trains.php">Valve Trains</a></li>
        <li><a href="ovens_and_furnaces.php">Ovens and Furnaces</a></li>
        <li><a href="web_drying.php">Web Drying</a></li>
        <li><a href="packaged_heaters.php">Packaged Heaters</a></li>
        <li><a href="control_panels.php">Control Panels</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><b>Part Sales</b></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="parts_line_card.php">Parts Line Card</a></li>
        <li><a href="parts_by_manufacturer_bryan_donkin.php">Parts By Manufacturers</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><b>Services</b></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="safety_audits.php">Safety Audits</a></li>
        <li><a href="spectrum_program.php">SPECTRUM Program</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="literature.php"><b>Literature</b></a>
    </li>
<li><a href="#"><b>About Us</b></a><ul>
        <li><a href="philosophy.php">Philosophy</a></li>
        <li><a href="jobs.php">Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="tech_tips.php">Technical Tips</a></li>
        <li><a href="inside_the_job.php">Inside the Job</a></li>
        <li><a href="company.php">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog">ETTER Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<ul id="slideshow">
    <li>
        <h3>Versa Plus 
        <br/><font color="#50658D">Gas Pressure Switches</font></h3>
        <span>Parts_by_Man_OK_By_Jon/Antunes/Versa_Plus_Gas_Pressure_Switches.gif</span>
        <p><br/>These sturdy gas switches are made with a durable plastic enclosure and a die-cast aluminum inlet base. They accurately monitor gas pressure and break the electrical control when pressure rises above or drops below the desired set point. Available in manual or automatic reset operation.
        <br/><br/>&#149; Adjustable gas pressure settings
        <br/>&#149; Ventless
        <br/>&#149; Mounts to any modular valve body
        <br/>&#149; Custom design per OEM specifications 
            &nbsp;&nbsp;available
        <br/>&#149; Available in low to high ranges
        <br/>&#149; Cost-effective pricing
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <b><font color="#494A4A">Printable Literature</font></b>
        <br/><br/><a href="http://www.ajantunes.com/Content/pdf/1020306 Rev A.pdf" target="_blank"><font size="1" color="#ACB0C3"><b>Specification Sheet</b></font></a></p>
        <a href="#"><img src="Parts_by_Man_OK_By_Jon/Antunes/thumbnails/Versa_Plus_Gas_Pressure_Switches_Thumbnail.gif" title="Versa Plus" alt="pink" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Model G 
        <br/><font color="#50658D">Gas Pressure Switches</font></h3>
        <span>Parts_by_Man_OK_By_Jon/Antunes/Model_G_Gas_Pressure_Switches.gif</span>
        <p><br/>Antunes Controls Model G gas pressure switches are now replaced with the new Versa Plus Gas switches. Use the table below to determine the Versa Plus Gas switch that replaces your Model G switch.
        <br/><br/>
        <table>
        <tr><td>Model G</td><td>Model G W.C. Range</td><td>Versa Model Versa No.</td><td>Versa W.C. Range</td><td>Versa mbar Range</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>HGP-G manual</td><td>2" to 20"</td><td>FGM-H050</td><td>8271005050</td><td>2" to 20"</td><td>5 to 50 mbar</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>HGP-G manual</td><td>8" to 35"</td><td>FGM-H087</td><td>8271006087</td><td>8" to 35"</td><td>20 to 87 mbar</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>HGP-G manual</td><td>10" to 60"</td><td>FGM-H0150</td><td>8271007150</td><td>10" to 60"</td><td>25 to 150 mbar</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>LGP-G manual</td><td>1" to 20"</td><td>FGM-L050</td><td>8271002050</td><td>1" to 20"</td><td>2.5 to 50 mbar</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>LGP-G manual</td><td>5" to 30"</td><td>FGM-L075</td><td>8271003075</td><td>5.2" to 30"</td><td>13 to 75 mbar</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>LGP-G manual</td><td>7" to 55"</td><td>FGM-L136</td><td>8271004136</td><td>6.8" to 54.5"</td><td>17 to 136 mbar</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>RHGP-G automatic</td><td>.8" to 4"</td><td>FGA-H010</td><td>8261005010</td><td>0.8" to 4"</td><td>2 to 10 mbar</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>RHGP-G automatic</td><td>2" to 20"</td><td>FGA-H050</td><td>8261006050</td><td>2" to 20"</td><td>5 to 50 mbar</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>RHGP-G automatic</td><td>5" to 35"</td><td>FGA-H087</td><td>8261007087</td><td>5" to 35"</td><td>13 to 87 mbar</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>RLGP-G automatic</td><td>.5" to 4"</td><td>FGA-L010</td><td>8261001010</td><td>0.5" to 4"</td><td>1.2 to 10 mbar</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>RLGP-G automatic</td><td>1" to 20"</td><td>FGA-L050</td><td>8261002050</td><td>1" to 20"</td><td>2.5 to 50 mbar</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>RLGP-G automatic</td><td>5" to 30"</td><td>FGA-L110</td><td>8261003110</td><td>4.8" to 44"</td><td>12 to 110 mbar</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>RLGP-G automatic</td><td>1 to 4 PSI</td><td>FGA-L275</td><td>8261004275<td><td>28" to 110"</td><td>70 to 275 mbar</td></tr>  
            </table>
        </p>
        <a href="#"><img src="Parts_by_Man_OK_By_Jon/Antunes/thumbnails/Model_G_Gas_Pressure_Switches_Thumbnail.gif" title="Model G" alt="green" /></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h3>SMD 
        <br/><font color="#50658D">Air Pressure Switches</font></h3>
        <span>Parts_by_Man_OK_By_Jon/Antunes/SMD_Air_Pressure_Switches.gif</span>
        <p><br/>These sensitive SMD sheet metal air differentiators are compact, easy to install, accurate and reliable. The SMDs switches monitor positive, vacuum or differential air pressure.
        <br/><br/>&#149; Sensitive diaphragm
        <br/>&#149; Snap-action electrical switch, S.P.D.T. rated 
            &nbsp;&nbsp;at 10 amps
        <br/>&#149; Ranges available from .17" up to 12" W.C.
        <br/>&#149; Custom design per OEM specifications 
            &nbsp;&nbsp;available
        <br/>&#149; Cost-effective pricing
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <b><font color="#494A4A">Printable Literature</font></b>
        <br/><br/><a href="http://www.ajantunes.com/Content/pdf/1020376.pdf" target="_blank"><font size="1" color="#ACB0C3"><b>Specification Sheet</b></font></a></p>
        <a href="#"><img src="Parts_by_Man_OK_By_Jon/Antunes/thumbnails/SMD_Air_Pressure_Switches_Thumbnail.gif" title="SMD" alt="green" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="wrapper2">
    <div id="fullsize">
        <div id="imgprev" class="imgnav" title="Previous Image"></div>
        <div id="imglink"></div>
        <div id="imgnext" class="imgnav" title="Next Image"></div>
        <div id="image"></div>
        <div id="information">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="thumbnails">
        <div id="slideleft" title="Slide Left"></div>
        <div id="slidearea">
            <div id="slider"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="slideright" title="Slide Right"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="compressed.js"></script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me to figure out why the table is not showing up?

Answer (score 1):

You have no table tags.

```
<li>
    <h3>Model G 
    <br/><font color="#50658D">Gas Pressure Switches</font></h3>
    <span>Parts_by_Man_OK_By_Jon/Antunes/Model_G_Gas_Pressure_Switches.gif</span>
    <p><br/>Antunes Controls Model G gas pressure switches are now replaced with the new Versa Plus Gas switches. Use the table below to determine the Versa Plus Gas switch that replaces your Model G switch.
    <br/><br/>
    <table>
    <tr><td>Model G</td><td>Model G W.C. Range</td><td>Versa Model Versa No.</td><td>Versa W.C. Range</td><td>Versa mbar Range</td></tr> 
    <tr><td>HGP-G manual</td><td>2" to 20"</td><td>FGM-H050</td><td>8271005050</td><td>2" to 20"</td><td>5 to 50 mbar</td></tr> 
    <tr><td>HGP-G manual</td><td>8" to 35"</td><td>FGM-H087</td><td>8271006087</td><td>8" to 35"</td><td>20 to 87 mbar</td></tr> 
    <tr><td>HGP-G manual</td><td>10" to 60"</td><td>FGM-H0150</td><td>8271007150</td><td>10" to 60"</td><td>25 to 150 mbar</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>LGP-G manual</td><td>1" to 20"</td><td>FGM-L050</td><td>8271002050</td><td>1" to 20"</td><td>2.5 to 50 mbar</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>LGP-G manual</td><td>5" to 30"</td><td>FGM-L075</td><td>8271003075</td><td>5.2" to 30"</td><td>13 to 75 mbar</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>LGP-G manual</td><td>7" to 55"</td><td>FGM-L136</td><td>8271004136</td><td>6.8" to 54.5"</td><td>17 to 136 mbar</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>RHGP-G automatic</td><td>.8" to 4"</td><td>FGA-H010</td><td>8261005010</td><td>0.8" to 4"</td><td>2 to 10 mbar</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>RHGP-G automatic</td><td>2" to 20"</td><td>FGA-H050</td><td>8261006050</td><td>2" to 20"</td><td>5 to 50 mbar</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>RHGP-G automatic</td><td>5" to 35"</td><td>FGA-H087</td><td>8261007087</td><td>5" to 35"</td><td>13 to 87 mbar</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>RLGP-G automatic</td><td>.5" to 4"</td><td>FGA-L010</td><td>8261001010</td><td>0.5" to 4"</td><td>1.2 to 10 mbar</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>RLGP-G automatic</td><td>1" to 20"</td><td>FGA-L050</td><td>8261002050</td><td>1" to 20"</td><td>2.5 to 50 mbar</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>RLGP-G automatic</td><td>5" to 30"</td><td>FGA-L110</td><td>8261003110</td><td>4.8" to 44"</td><td>12 to 110 mbar</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>RLGP-G automatic</td><td>1 to 4 PSI</td><td>FGA-L275</td><td>8261004275<td><td>28" to 110"</td><td>70 to 275 mbar</td></tr>  
        </p>
    </table>
    <a href="#"><img src="Parts_by_Man_OK_By_Jon/Antunes/thumbnails/Model_G_Gas_Pressure_Switches_Thumbnail.gif" title="Model G" alt="green" /></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that, however it is sill not showing up.

Comment: How are you expecting it to look?  I'm not sure what you mean by "not showing up".  The content should still appear either way.

Comment: The content or table does not appear.

Comment: hmm there must be something else going on.  Can you post a link to the page, or possibly the entire contents of it?

Comment: here is a link www.etterengineering.com/parts_by_manufacturer_antunes_controls.php

Comment: I think the problem is in the slideshow javascript.  For some reason it is dropping the table when it creates the slideshow